# Cucumber Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/cucumberexpressions/ParameterTypeRegistry

Tags: cucumber

I am facing an error when I try to run a simple cucumber feature file using `junit`. Any help will be awesome.

[my feature file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOdSu.png)

Answer (score 0):

U need to also add `cucumber-expressions, datatable and datatable-dependencies` jar.
[image]

Easier to just use maven to manage dependencies. Just add below dependencies to the POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If u are using junit runner add the `cucumber-junit` dependency. For testng runner add `cucumber-testng`.

Comment: Hi Hopper,  Thanks for your response. once i added cucumber-expressions, datatable and datatable-dependencies jar to the project, the issue was solved. Thank You....